# QTIFW wizardstyle

Tags: qt

Having some trouble setting a WizardStyle in QTIFW I have read the documentation and cant understand why the following doesn't work.

```
<'WizardStyle>Mac<'/WizardStyle>
<'Background>logo.png<'Background>
(Obviously excluding ' char)
```

Qt Documentation:

> Background - Filename for an image used as QWizard::BackgroundPixmap
>   (only used by MacStyle). WizardStyle - Set the wizard style to be used
>   ("Modern", "Mac", "Aero" or "Classic").

I get the following error:

```
Caught exception: Error in config\config.xml, line 8, column 17: Unexpected element 'WizardStyle'

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Installer>
    <Name>Dave Installer</Name>
    <Version>1.2.3</Version>
    <Title>Dave Installer</Title>
    <Publisher>Dave</Publisher>
    <Icon>qticon</Icon>
    <WizardStyle>Mac</WizardStyle>
    <Background>logo.png</Background>
    <StartMenuDir>Super App</StartMenuDir>
    <TargetDir>@RootDir@InstallationDirectory</TargetDir>
    <RunProgram>@TargetDir@/qt</RunProgram>
    <RunProgramDescription>Qt Installer</RunProgramDescription> 
</Installer>
```

Comment: `WizardStyle` isn't available until later versions of Qt IFW, so what version are you running?

Comment: Sorry using version 1.5.0, on Windows 7

Comment: Can you post the whole config.xml? The error may be cause by the preceding lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to comments made in bug [470](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-470) and [452](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTIFW-452), the `WizardStyle` tag implementation never made it into the v1.5 release (at least the compiled binary).  So you'll have to get a later release (the master is at ~v2.0).